# Why is my trigger not able to identify the column?

Tags: sql-server, date, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger for a particular dataset,This is the code that I am using

```
Create trigger tr_minimum_salary 
On tble_SalesReps_TR 
After Update as
If update(salary) and datediff(YY,DateOfHire,getdate())>=15
    Begin
    Raiserror('Employees with more than 15 years of experience cannot recieve less than 100,000 $',0,1)
Rollback
Return
END
```

It gives me an error saying 'Invalid column name DateofHire'

While the following code works

```
   Select * from tble_SalesReps_TR
   Where datediff(YY,DateOfHire,getdate())>=15
```

What am I doing wrong with the trigger code?

EDIT: Here's another trigger code which did work, without having to use the "FROM" statement

```
  Create trigger tr_nochange_december
  On tbls_products_tr
  After Update as
  If update(UnitsOnOrder) and datepart(m,(getdate()))<>12
    Begin
    Raiserror('These products can only be purchased in December',0,1)
    Rollback
    Return
    END
```

Comment: Also, be careful here. The UPDATE function does NOT evaluate if the values are the same. It only checks to see if that column is included in the original update statement. This is a very common misconception. UPDATE(Salary) will return true even if the value is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers have to have valid TSQL in them.

This is not valid TSQL:

```
If update(salary) and datediff(YY,DateOfHire,getdate())>=15
```

Without a `FROM` clause, TSQL doesn't know what `DateOfHire` is.

Comment: But it is able to identify the salary column, I used another code a snippet of which I have added in the bottom part, it works fine. Plus I am referring to the table using an  "ON" statement, does that not work? It worked for me with the code at the bottom.

Comment: That is part of the UPDATE functionality. Consider that this trigger is an update. That means you have DateOfHire in both the inserted and deleted virtual tables. How could the engine possibly know which one you are trying to refer too?

Comment: Please read about the UPDATE function on MSDN, and understand why it works.  It's functionality does not extend to the rest of the code in the trigger.  The fact that you refer to the table in the "ON" clause of the initial CREATE TRIGGER statement does not automatically create an implied reference to that table for the rest of the trigger.  Believe me (and Sean) that you have to specify it in the rest of the code.  I think you would benefit from looking up some examples of Triggers on the internet to see how they work.  You seem to have some misunderstandings of their basic principles.